# I want my View recognize the class of another View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I have 4 handlebar helper blocks named `{{#decoy-Input class="fieldInput"}} {{/decoy-Input}}` and I want to refer to them all with Jquery by calling their class, 'fieldInput'

The fieldInput class is not called though when I use `{{#decoy-Input class="fieldInput"}} {{/decoy-Input}}`

I'm guessing this has to do with the order in which the views were rendered, but I'd like a second opinion.

And here is the view that defines them.

```
VpcYeoman.DecoyInputView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  click: function(e) {
    console.log('CanFocusInputView clicked')
    $('.fieldInput').removeClass('.focusedInput'); 
    this.$().addClass('focusedInput');
  },
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('decoy-Input', VpcYeoman.DecoyInputView);
```

**To get the green check, you will need to** provide a way to call all 4 of the `{{#decoy-Input class="fieldInput"}} {{/decoy-Input}}` blocks inside of the Decoy Input click function. It doesn't need to be with JQuery.

I realize that a solution like '`this.$().parent().siblings('.objectInput').children().removeClass('focusedInput');`' would also solve this issue, but it feels like a poor work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those cases were you really just want to leverage Ember's run loop and DOM hooks.

Wrap the whole shibang in a view:

```
{{#view VpcYeoman.InputsView}}
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
  <input type="email" name="email"/>
  <!-- even better, use the input helper to bind the value -->
  {{input type="checkbox" name=name}}
{{/view}}
```

Now, fire up that view and make use of the `didInsertElement` hook to write some boring jQuery :) And by boring, I mean not Ember.

```
VpcYeoman.InputsView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function () {
    var $inputs = this.$('input');

    $inputs.on('focus', function (e) {
      $(this).addClass('focusedInput');
    });

    $inputs.on('blur', function (e) {
      $(this).removeClass('focusedInput');
    });
  }
});
```

That should give you what you want without too much ceremony. Hope that helps, and let me know if I can further explain!

Comment: This answer is much better! Thanks for the help

Comment: So just to be clear, when Im using jquery to affect the DOM, I should put that logic in a view and then wrap that view around the DOM Elements I want to be affected?

Comment: @IanSteffy Sorry I wasn't paying attention and didn't see this question. That is one way to do it. You could also create a custom view that doesn't have any wrapped html, but it generates its own html dynamically. You could also create a component. I prefer to use the pattern I've shown you because it is super easy to read, at least for me. Hope that helps!

Comment: That helped a lot! In your answer, shouldn't that {{view}} have a # in front of 'view' because it also has a closing {{/view}}?

Comment: Oh whoops yep, you are right. that was a typo. Updated my answer.